# Solving an integral with exponential function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I try to solve the following integral
$$\int_a^b \exp\left\{-\lambda \left(\frac{y}{2x^2}-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right\} dx$$ for $\lambda>0$ and $y \in  \mathbb{R}$. Do you see any relation to any known integral or another way to solve it?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This spits out something in terms of the error function $\text{erfi}(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

let $t=\frac1x-\frac2y$, we get
$$e^{\frac{2\lambda}y}\int_{\frac1b-\frac2y}^{\frac1a-\frac2y}e^{-\frac{\lambda y}2t^2}\left(t+\frac2y\right)^2dt,$$
because there exist an integral like
$$\int e^{-x^2}x^2dx=-\frac12xe^{-x^2}+\frac12\int e^{-x^2}dx,$$
so ...

Comment: It seems that $u$ is the $x$ of the original equation. I do not understand the last term. I would expect the exponent -2 rather than +2.

Comment: oh, yes, you are right, it's $x$ not $u$, thx